# assistance needed with sql statements/expressions

Tags: sql

New to sql statements etc and I have an issue with what i am doing using squirrelSQL on linux machine

I Created a table and used the following sql statements:-

```
INSERT INTO FIRSTTABLE VALUES
    (11,'TEN','STEVE'),(21,'TWENTY','JO'),(31,'THIRTY','KIDS')

ALTER TABLE FIRSTTABLE
ADD SURNAME VARCHAR(15);
```

this works fine however when i attempt to insert data/values into the the surname row   i keep experiencing errors, the SQL statement i am using is:-

```
 INSERT INTO FIRSTTABLE (SURNAME)
     VALUES ('THOMAS'),('THOMAS'),('THOMAS'),('THOMAS');
```

This particular statement returns the following error:-

> Error: Column 'ID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
>   SQLState:  23502
>   ErrorCode: 30000

I only wish to add data/values into the surname column,after creating a new column with the alter table statement, i have tried many different combinations including using a SELECT statement prior to the INSERT statement above which also gives errors any guidance will be greatly appreciated,

Comment: make the ID an IDENTITY column which is auto-increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting into Surname, without assigning a value to the other fields. You are getting this error message because ID is blank, and should not.

Understand that `INSERT` creates new rows. If you wish to modify existing rows, use [`UPDATE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

In this case you could use `UPDATE FIRSTTABLE SET SURNAME='THOMAS';`
 Omitting the `WHERE` clause affects all the fields in the table.

Hope it helps, and good luck in your learning process!

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The approach is wrong, you need to:

```
UPDATE FIRSTTABLE SET SURNAME='THOMAS' WHERE ID IN (11, 21, 31)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting will add a new row to the table. So you need to **update** a row using

`UPDATE FIRSTTABLE SET SURNAME="THOMAS" WHERE ID=11`